# XML: Docbook Error with using para with @id

Tags: xml, docbook

I've been trying to get pages references to work for my xsl-fo and concept is to add a blank tag you can reference as the the last page that will be processed.  So my table of contents looks something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article
   xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">

<xi:includes
   ... (lots of them)
<xi:includes>

   <para id="last-page"/>
</article>
```

So ideally i just reference `last-page`.  But with this i get an validation error:

[ERROR]contents.xml:154:27: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'para'. One of '{"http://docbook.org/ns/docbook":section, "http://docbook.org/ns/docbook":simplesect, "http://docbook.org/ns/docbook":glossary, "http://docbook.org/ns/docbook":bibliography, "http://docbook.org/ns/docbook":index, "http://docbook.org/ns/docbook":toc, "http://docbook.org/ns/docbook":appendix, "http://docbook.org/ns/docbook":acknowledgements, "http://docbook.org/ns/docbook":colophon}' is expected.

[ERROR]contents.xml:154:27: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'id' is not allowed to appear in element 'para'.

I've tried removing that docbook from the schema, and I get other errors.  What should i try instead to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The schema does not allow a para element at the end of the article. As the error message says, one of section, simplesect, glossary, bibliography, index, toc, appendix, acknowledgements, colophon is expected.
2. The **id** attribute has been replaced by **xml:id** in DocBook 5.
3. I guess that the purpose is to produce "Page x of y" page numbering in the output. Do take a look at the "Page x of y numbering" section here: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/PrintHeaders.html#ConsecutivePageNumbers.